# How should a paramete of type "data URL" be declared in an OpenApi schema

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is it possible to declare a parameter in an OpeanApi 3 schema as being "data URL"? If I understand the specification, the format can be basically anything, but should I use some specific format or should I just do it like this?

```
MyObject:
  title: MyObject
  description: Information about my object
  type: object
  required:
    - myData
  properties:
    myData:
      type: string
      format: data URL
```

Comment: By "data URL", do you mean this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 1):

You can define a data URL as a `string`

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined value for `format` in the spec to describe a data URL: [OpenAPI Data Types](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/). However, the specs says

> However, format is an open value, so you can use any formats, even not those defined by the OpenAPI Specification

So the version above would be possible, even though OpenAPI generators would just ignore it.